# Can I configure a router to control access from my children's telephones as well as other devices?

Tags: access-control, router

Our children use both iPhones and Motorola phones. We get worn down by the fights about "confiscating" the phones, and want to be able to block access to the Internet on a device-by-device basis when we need to. Is there a router or other device/configuration that can control access on such a basis?

Comment: What do you mean by "control access"?

Comment: Phone use the cellular networks as well as your home's wifi. If you block wifi access, the phone switches to the cell network. You cannot control the cell networks. As for wifi, you can use the router's MAC address filtering to only allow known MAC addresses and revoke access to one of your kid's devices.

Comment: According to http://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201304 you may be able to turn mobile data off on the iPhone and turn parental lock on. With parental lock enabled the user may not be able to enable cellular data without a pin/password setup by parental lock

Comment: Is the Motorola phone Android or Symbian?

Answer (score 1):

You could block the devices based on their [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) address. In short, a MAC address is a unique identifier for a device. This method can be used until your kids are smart enough to [spoof](http://www.wired.com/2008/01/mac-address-spo/) them.

In your router you should be able to view all the assigned IP addresses, including their MAC addresses in the [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) configuration. Then you could enable MAC address white-listing by entering the MAC address of the devices to which you want to allow internet access.

As you have not mentioned what type of router you have, I've added this (random) picture so you get an idea of what you're looking for:

[image]

Aside from the technical aspect, why not tell your kids they will lose their phone for a week if or when they start fighting?! And if they do it again, they'll lose it for a month.

Technology should not be a solution for your children's misbehaviour IMHO.

Comment: Keep in mind that they can still use mobile data, and if you're the one paying for mobile data, this solution could backfire.

Comment: You're assuming they have mobile data, in security assumption is the mother of all ........ As this, among other things, was not mentioned in the initial post, I decided not to assume this.

Comment: Fair enough, but it's a smartphone, after all... Plus I don't see how assuming more access than they actually have would be bad for security.

Comment: I think the OP is saying that he takes away the phone as a result of misbehaviour, then the child complains about the lack of phone. I think he is looking for a way for the child to keep the phone, but limit its use.